# Compare records within each group in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

| id | amount | date | group | master_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a201 | 100 | 12-10-2022 | a | a201 |
| a101 | 70 | 12-10-2022 | a | a201 |
| a102 | 90 | 12-10-2022 | a | a201 |
| b24 | 150 | 12-10-2022 | b | b24 |
| b13 | 120 | 12-10-2022 | b | b24 |
| c71 | 10 | 12-10-2022 | c | c71 |
| c12 | 100 | 12-10-2022 | c | c71 |
| c1 | 12 | 12-10-2022 | c | c71 |

I need to compare the records within each group (a, b, c here) and generate a similarity score. The value to be checked is under master_id column (i.e. for group a, a201 is to be checked with a101 and a102). The attributes to be checked is the amount and date. If date is within 5 days, score is 1 and if the amount is within a difference of 10, the score is 1 in all other cases, score is 0. The similarity score will be the sum of the 2 individual scores.

Expected output

| id | amount | date | group | master_id | amount_score | date_score | similarity_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a201 | 100 | 12-10-2022 | a | a201 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| a101 | 70 | 11-10-2022 | a | a201 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| a102 | 90 | 12-10-2022 | a | a201 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b24 | 150 | 12-10-2022 | b | b24 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| b13 | 145 | 25-10-2022 | b | b24 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| c71 | 10 | 12-10-2022 | c | c71 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| c12 | 100 | 30-10-2022 | c | c71 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c1 | 12 | 11-10-2022 | c | c71 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

What is the best way to do this operation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
scores = (df[["amount", "date"]]
            .sub(df.groupby("group")[["amount", "date"]].transform("first"))
            .abs()
            .lt([10, pd.Timedelta("5 days")])
            .astype(int)
            .add_suffix("_score"))

scores["similarity_score"] = scores.sum(axis="columns")

new_df = df.join(scores)
```

- take the difference of each amount & date values from that of each group's first values
- take the absolute value of differences and compare against thresholds
- True/False is obtained; map them to 1/0 via type casting
- add the "score" suffix to the new columns
- compute the total scores and join with the original dataframe

to get

```py
>>> new_df

     id  amount       date group master_id  amount_score  date_score  similarity_score
0  a201     100 2022-12-10     a      a201             1           1                 2
1  a101      70 2022-12-10     a      a201             0           1                 1
2  a102      90 2022-12-10     a      a201             0           1                 1
3   b24     150 2022-12-10     b       b24             1           1                 2
4   b13     120 2022-12-10     b       b24             0           1                 1
5   c71      10 2022-12-10     c       c71             1           1                 2
6   c12     100 2022-12-10     c       c71             0           1                 1
7    c1      12 2022-12-10     c       c71             1           1                 2
```